# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" while using str.indexOf function

Tags: javascript

I get this message in the cosole: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`  and it's literally making me crazy! There is no mistakes that I can see, but maybe someone else can help me.

```
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation');

console.log(nav);
console.log(nav[0]);
var nav_e = nav[0];
  //var searched = nav[0].search('<a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=11">Deck - Lab</a>');

  if (nav_e.indexOf('<a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=11">Deck - Lab</a>') > -1) {

    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('post_body');
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var pbelement_encoded = '';
    var pbelement = ''

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var element = list[i];

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

          var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
          var result2 = result.replace(/fhvjgvghepoapeoaareupo/g,'');


          element.innerHTML = (xmlhttp.responseText.replace(/fhvjgvghepoapeoaareupo/g,''));
        }
      }

      pbelement_encoded = encodeURIComponent(element.innerHTML);
      pbelement = 'pb='+pbelement_encoded;

      //alert(pbelement);

      xmlhttp.open("POST","http://theepicsurge.altervista.org/PostAnalyzer.php",false);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
      xmlhttp.send(pbelement);
    }
  }
}
```

The error ocures in the first `if` statement: `if (nav_e.indexOf('<a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=11">Deck - Lab</a>') > -1) {`

I also tried replacing the `nav_e.indexOf` with `nav_e.search`, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: The thing references by "nav_e" must not actually be a string. It's not `null` or `undefined`, but it's not a string (or String). Add a call to `console.log("nav_e is a " + (typeof nav_e));`

Comment: It's HTMLElement actually, the result of `document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[0]`. To check its contents, go for `nav[0].innerHTML.indexOf(...)` instead. Or, what's better, check for the corresponding element directly (with `querySelector('a[href="forumdisplay.php?fid=11"]')`

Comment: @raina77ow oh duhh - I had scrolled that off the top :)

Comment: @raina77ow That was really helpful! Why didn't you post it as an answer? Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this type of error in your application - `undefined is not a function`, it usually means one thing: you're trying to call a method of some object, believing this object to be of `X` type, while actually it's of `Y` type.

This case is particularly interesting because it illustrates a popular confusion between Elements (of DOM) and their corresponding representations (i.e., strings). To be more specific, these lines...

```
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation');
var nav_e = nav[0];
```

... will populate a `nav_e` with HTMLELement, the first one of those with `navigation` class.

*(it's easier to get that element with `querySelector('.navigation')`, btw)*

Now, `nav_e` has some contents - but it's not a string, and it doesn't have `indexOf` property both on itself and on its prototype chain. To implement your original idea, the code should actually be written like this:

```
if (nav_e.innerHTML.indexOf('<a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=11') !== -1) { /* */ }
```

Still, there's a better idea: reusing the DOM methods to look for the corresponding element. Like this:

```
if (nav_e.querySelector('a[href="forumdisplay.php?fid=11"]')) { /* ... */ }
```

... as `querySelector` method returns `null` if element isn't found.

Comment: Sweet, the second Options seems much simpler and hopefully faster! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

indexOf method apply on array.and here you apply indexOf method on first element of array not on array `var nav_e = nav[0];` so replace this code:

```
if (nav_e.indexOf('<a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=11">Deck - Lab</a>') > -1)
```

to

```
if (nav.indexOf('<a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=11">Deck - Lab</a>') > -1)
```

Comment: That doesn't wok, as nav is not a string (As raina77ow said)